# Misbehavior of Scanf function in C

Tags: c, scanf

Consider the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int p = 0;
    char a = 0;
    while(p == 0)
    {
        p = scanf("%[abc]c",&a);
    }
    printf("%c",a);
}
```

I know if you enter a character except `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'`, value of the getting character from input would not be set into the variable `a`.

The **problem** is if you enter a value except the specified characters, the above loop never and never terminates. Apparently, after getting a not specified character in `scanf`, it will not get any character in the following loop iteration. *Where is the origin of this problem?*

Comment: Do you think that `[]` works as a kind of modifier to the `%c` conversion? If so, that's not how it works.

Comment: you can debug and see the behavior is as what I said, in the front side.